# Python PyCharm debug is not working properly - click to show value

Tags: debugging, pycharm, settings

[image]

Hi, 1hour ago I clicked at something by mistake at the debug, and since then the debug been ruined.
I cant see the values unless I click show value.
Now, when working with debug in order to solve complicated problems, its pretty much annoying.
How to solve this problem? google doesn't say anything.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody wants to know:
Go to debug at PyCharm.
There is a settings there.
Look for variable loading policy.
then click asynchronously.
And debug again and it should be fixed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).